# Add new row dynamically bootstrap-datetimepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table:

```
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><div id="date" class="input-group date"><input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div></div></td>
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
```

I use the button to create a new row dynamically:

```
    $("#addInt").click(function() {
        $("#intTbl").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            $.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
                tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });
    });
```

I use `bootstrap-datetimepicker` to create date field in the form, but when I dynamically add a new row, the date field is not working.

Comment: Some bootstrap plugins can be delegated using `selector` option. Checking the DOC, it appears this one doesn't implement it so you should call this plugin on new specific elements once added to the DOM or find a workaround as in @Simo's answer, even this asnwer should be tested, not sure it will work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<tr>
<td><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div></div></td>
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>

$('body').on('focus',".date", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});​
```

Instead of :

```
$('#date').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: Please consider to us `one()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: I meant: `$('body').one('focus',"input.datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});​` To avoid recalling plugin each time you focus element

Comment: @Simo Does not work, I use $('#date').datetimepicker();

Comment: the ID must be unique for each element, remove id attribute and change the script to $('body').on('focus',".date", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});​

Comment: @Simo you are correct, i was thinking `one()` to work once for each matched elements, not just once for all matched elements. And seems obvious now because event is bound to BODY level

Comment: @Simo, how can use the same id?

Comment: ID must unique for each element, if you can do that, use className instead.

Comment: @Simo, this is working when user click on the textbox first, but it wont load if the user click on the calendar icon at the side of the textbox.

Comment: then add .date class to the icon too